# How to create a custom segment condition using a between expression

Tags: exm, list-manager, segmentation, segmented-list

Is it possible to create a custom segment condition that you pass in two values into and then perform a conditional expression between two values.

e.g. Create a segmented list if the IndexedContact last visit date was between 5 and 10 days ago?

All the code I've found to help so far uses TypedQueryableOperatorCondition which only checks a single value against a single parameter e.g.:

```
return this.GetCompareExpression<DateTime>((Expression<Func<IndexedContact, DateTime>>) (c => c.LatestVisitDate), DateUtil.ParseDateTime(this.Value, DateTime.MinValue));
```

I'm using Sitecore version 8.2 and Email Experience Manager version 3.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TypedQueryableOperatorCondition and TypedQueryableStringOperatorCondition are helpers, and are both using `Sitecore.Rules.Conditions.WhenCondition<T>` behind the scene, so you could implement your own condition based on this.

As an (untested) example:

```
public class CustomLatestVisitDateCondition<T> : WhenCondition<T>, IQueryableRule<IndexedContact>
    where T: VisitorRuleContext<IndexedContact>
{

    public Expression<Func<IndexedContact, bool>> InitPredicate { protected get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<IndexedContact, bool>> ResultPredicate { get; protected set; }

    public string FromValue { get; set; }
    public string ToValue { get; set; }

    protected override bool Execute(T ruleContext)
    {
        var from = DateUtil.ParseDateTime(FromValue, DateTime.MinValue);
        var to = DateUtil.ParseDateTime(ToValue, DateTime.MinValue);

        this.ApplyFilter(ruleContext, c => c.LatestVisitDate >= from && c.LatestVisitDate <= to);
        return true;
    }

    private void ApplyFilter(T ruleContext, Expression<Func<IndexedContact, bool>> expression)
    {
        ResultPredicate = (InitPredicate ?? ruleContext.Where).And(expression);
        if (InitPredicate != null)
        {
            return;
        }

        ruleContext.Where = ResultPredicate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Jacob, when I try to do this Sitecore complains at run time that I'm using `VisitorRuleContext` instead of the plain `RuleContext, thus throwing a TypeLoadException. Is there any reason why I'm not being passed a VisitorRuleContext?